# Failed to send HTML mails using PHP mail()

Tags: php, html, email

Strange things happening to me. I'm trying to send a HTML mail, using the php `mail()` function, but no luck here. Even when I copy/paste a piece of code literally, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Here is the piece of code I use:

```
        $message = "<html><body>";
        $message .= "<table rules='all' style='border-color: #666;' cellpadding='10'>";
        $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";       

        $to = 'me@gmail.com';

        $subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

        $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
          echo 'Your message has been sent.';
        } else {
          echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
        }
```

And this is what my e-mail looks like...:

```
Reply-To: me@gmail.com

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Message-Id: <20110703234551.A9D6153DAB@apache10.hostbasket.com>
Date: Mon, 4 Jul 2011 01:45:51 +0200 (CEST)

<html><body><table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10"><tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td></tr><tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td></tr><tr><td><strong>Type of Change:</strong> </td></tr><tr><td><strong>Urgency:</strong> </td></tr><tr><td><strong>URL To Change (main):</strong> </td></tr><tr><td><strong>NEW Content:</strong> </td></tr></table></body></html>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7 and my e-mail client is Sparrow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't see where the variable `$email` was set, but I'm guessing that there might be an extra line break at the end of your `$email` variable.  This would have the effect of putting in two linebreaks after the `From:` header and before the `Reply-to:` , which signals the start of the body of the message and the completion of the headers.

Try:

```
$email = trim($email);
```

before constructing the message.  Since there appears to be an extra line break after the `Reply-to` header as well, my case is even stronger for an extra break in `$email`.

**UPDATE**

Also try changing the linebreaks to PHP's native format on the system where the code will run.  This is done by replacing `\r\n` with `PHP_EOL`

```
    $headers = "From: " . $email . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Would sendmail send that mail with the extra linebreaks in the headers?

Comment: @Jarred Farrish Yes, I believe `mail()` passes the block of headers unmodified to sendmail, followed by the message body, and sendmail sends them assuming they are correctly formatted.  That is the reason mail injection is problematic.  http://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php

Comment: Nice link. I always thought sendmail was real touchy as far as linebreaks.

Comment: The extra `$email = trim($email)` didn't work out... Still getting the same un-HTML message of before...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful link to sending html emails in php

http://blog.twigahost.com/how-to-send-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a mailer class. They give you the possibility to use smtp auth, so every mail will be passed through. A few examples:

- http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
- http://swiftmailer.org/
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html