# PHP mail(): Header appears in mail body

Tags: php, email, header

I have a problem with a mailing application I'm currently developing with php on a linux server. After sending an email to a bunch of different addresses with different clients on it, sometimes these mails can't be read by the receivers.
For example the body appears to start with this:

```
boundary="=_2cac04098ebf51c342bd57eab2200e38"
Message-ID: <lo5huc.id4ip6qutsch.lforce.de>
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2011 06:01:24 +0200 (CEST)

--=_2cac04098ebf51c342bd57eab2200e38
```

I really have no clue what's happening to my mails. Each line in the header is separated by `\n`, the boundary entry has a leading `\t`. Though the client seems to read a line break which is not there while parsing my header. It also happens in other parts of the header.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? Please help me!

Andy

UPDATE: I'm pretty sure it's no coding error. I've been coding this mail stuff for years (even wrote my own mail client) and it worked perfectly. Right now we use the RMAIL class which is also from a bigger open source project. I think it's more like a problem with my system configuration... but that's just a guess.

Comment: Looks like a MIME boundary. Are you using a library (like PEAR::Mail) to send the emails?

Comment: it's to long and in too many parts to post it in here. It's kind of this:
$header .= "From: some@test.de\nContent-Type: text/html\n"
Really nothing special.

I'm using pure mail() and rMail

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566335/failed-to-send-html-mails-using-php-mail/6566349#6566349

Comment: @Andy: Don't build your own mime envelopes. Too error prone and far too much work. Use Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org) or PHPMailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com) instead. They're far far easier to use.

Comment: Seconded - SwiftMailer will rock your world.

Comment: Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n) instead. Using only \n does not comply with RFC 2822.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you seperate every header line correctly, for instance:

```
<?php
   //To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

   // Additional headers
   $headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

   // Mail it
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: and separating lines with PHP_EOL... I once had a glance and thought it might happen because of the storage of the sending file itself (unix format or dos format)... but the error reappeared again.

Comment: So did you try the \r\n seperators rather than just using the \n ? This always works just fine for me. And I doubt it's the system settings because the e-mail IS sent, it's just that your content shows issues in your e-mail app. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using PHPMailer, easy to use, takes care of all nesseccery headers, easy attachment sending, multiple recipients etc.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer

Comment: I'm desperate... I'll give it a try and wait. Unfortunatelly I can't reproduce this error. It doesn't happen on any of my machines / devices. Just on the computer of some customers, mostly running Windows XP...

Comment: Well, you should find out what mail clients they use. Making HTML in e-mails work as intended on all mail clients isn't an easy job... Good luck!