# PHP/HTML Code Renders as Text in Email: Any Insight?

Tags: php, html, email

I've tried many header changes to no avail.

Could it be the email server? Or am I missing something crucial?

I would like to see more than the code rendered as text in the resultant email.

Thanks!

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
$body = '';
$body .= '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here is a Copy of Your Order</h1>'; 
    $body .= '<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Units</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>';
    $total = 0;

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {

    $body .= "<tr>
        <td>{$item['item']}</td>
        <td>\${$item['unitprice']}</td>
        <td>{$item['quantity']}</td>
        <td>$".($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity'])."</td>
        </tr>";
        $total += ($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity']);
    }
    $body .= '</table>';
    $body .= "<p>Grand total: \$$total</p>";
    $body .='</body></html>';
}
?> 

<?php
echo $body;
$to      =  'xxxx@gmail.com';
$subject =  'Fill This Order';
$headers =  'From: xxxx@gmail.com' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: The email client is capable of receiving HTML email? Have you tried `imap_mail()`? What headers have you tried?

Comment: Hi cmt, I think it might be an email client issue. I'll try imap_mail() and report back.

Comment: As a curiosity, why aren't you using one of the mirad libraries available to send email for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a tutorial about how to send a mail with html code in it: [Sending Nice HTML Email with PHP](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

work around it, what they got works.

as you can easly see there, the headers sent is:

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

they diffrence you can see is mostly: `\r\n` in every end of line.
this could be your problem because without it it can be something like:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
```

and in headers... this could be: `'MIME-Version: 1.0Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`
and not work..

i think you should take a look in the link i added and modify your code by it.

**EDIT:**

i think i found it!  you sent `mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers);`

while PHP mail function uses:

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

you can see here how to use the mail function: [The PHP mail() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)

the thing i think heppend is you sent `$message` which does not exsits and the headers are not sent as they should.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. It still comes through as text. I'm thinking it might be an email server thing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566335/failed-to-send-html-mails-using-php-mail?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Such a noob mistake I made. Thanks so much for your time. :)

Comment: sure! i am more than happy i could help :)  don't worry, everyone make dumb mistakes once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping out PHP_EOL for "\r\n"?