# how to send an HTML content via php mail()

Tags: apache, php

I am trying to send an HTML e-mail using this code but all i am getting is FALSE from the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

The error_log is empty.

Can someone tell me why mail() is not working?

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>SDFSDF</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>VXCVSDF</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$to = 'my_mail@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: USER NAME"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: USER EMAIL"."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"."\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Your message has been sent.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
}
```

Comment: Is this a local or remote environment? Has mail() worked previously? Is there an active [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) (e.g. sendmail/postfix) on your server environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566335/failed-to-send-html-mails-using-php-mail?rq=1

Comment: I checked, his code was properly working on my server! Any luck with the problem you got?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug PHP mail() function.

After checking your script, I can confirm that your code is working fine. It's something with your server or/and PHP configuration.

Start with this little snippet to see what is happening:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', -1);
echo '<br>I am : ' . `whoami`.'<br>';
$result = mail('myaddress@mydomain.com','This is the test','This is a test.');
echo '<hr>Result was: ' . ( $result === FALSE ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE') . ' ('. $result. ')';
echo '<hr>';
echo phpinfo();
```

After output, check your `sendmail_path`, in most case `sendmail_path` uses `sendmail` MTA:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Edit your `php.ini` file, set the following and don't forget to restart httpd server:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Check log files at `/var/log/maillog`, it could really help you to solve the problem.

If you still have a problem, just take a good look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org), [PEAR's Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) or [Zend Framework's Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) an excellent, comprehensive, modern PHP mailing library. It will be easy to debug your problem after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can using phpmailer for this way!

- https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Hope this help!